# What software is good and complete useful for drawing anime?

Tags: software-recommendation

I am a looking for a software that *you can draw using a mouse* 
example: many users are using Paint Tool Sai for drawing and sketching anime.

I am looking for that kind of software, full version and free with no payment.

I`ll show you what it looks like...

[image]

this is what paint tool sai looks like.. I am searching for a similar program like this one.. but more complete and useful. I got the same program and it said at the top of the bar 3 days trial, so I only downloaded the trial.

Can you guys help me and suggest a program?

Comment: Please add to your post that you are looking specifically for FREE software.

Answer (score 1):

I would not know, because I've always used Photoshop.  This question was very easily solved with a Google search though.

You could try [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/)

I've never used it, so I can't speak on its behalf, but I have seen several posts on here about it, so I know it's probably decent.

Answer (score 1):

If you need open source drawing applications i would consider:

- [Krita](https://krita.org/), its a bit nicer in this use than gimp
- you could also try [myPaint](http://mypaint.org/)
- [art weaver](http://www.artweaver.de/en) is pretty good too.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Autodesk Sketch Book pro](https://www.sketchbook.com/), it is very good and powerful for this type usage.

Comment: Hi Yasen, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. Could you please motivate and explain why this answers the question? Thanks! If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!